# Why "(uint8)0U" appears to the static code analysis tool as a signed operand?

Tags: c, static-code-analysis, misra, cert

When I run static code analysis it says:

`Bitwise operator "~" has a signed operand "(uint8)0U"`.

How come this operand is signed while I am explicitly casting it to `uint8` which is equivalent to `unsigned char` and also postfixing it with literal `U` which stands for unsigned integer?

Comment: It gets promoted to int, cast it to unsigned int instead.

Answer (score 6):

`0U` has type `unsigned int` and `(uint8)0U` has type `unsigned char`, but like all types smaller than `int`, it gets promoted to `int` in an expression context such as an operand to `~`.

You should just remove the cast and use `~0U`.

Note however that on systems with 16- or 32-bit ints using two's complement representation (almost all current systems<sup>*</sup>):

- `~0U` has type `unsigned int` and evaluates to `0xFFFFFFFF` (`0xFFFF` if `int` has 16 bits).
- `~(uint8)0U` has type `int` and evaluates to `-1`, which has the same bit representation, whereas
- `(uint8)~0U` evaluates to `0xFF` with type `int`.

Depending on the context, one might be more appropriate than the other.

The static analyser underscores the often unexpected side effect of the C integer promotion rules...

---

<sup>* embedded 8- and 16-bit CPUs use 16-bit ints, whereas laptop, desktop and server main CPUs use 32-bit ints. Non two's complement representations for signed integers are obsolete and will be removed from the C2x of the C Standard</sup>

Answer (score 0):

See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules), the ~ operator applies the integer promotions on its operand. Or study appendix C of MISRA C:2012.

MISRA or not, casting to a *small integer type* such as `uint8_t` before applying `~` doesn't make any sense, it can even be considered a bug in your case since you convert a `unsigned int` to `uint8_t`, which in turn gets implicitly promoted to `int` and you end up with a signed `-1` which isn't intended.

However, from a MISRA C:2012 perspective, a static analyser should only bother to check the type before implicit promotion. As per rule 10.1 the only allowed operand of `~` is one that's *essentially unsigned*. That is, code such as `~(uint8_t)0U` is strange and bad, but as far as I can tell, MISRA C:2012 compliant.

The older deprecated MISRA C:2004 had a requirement that you should cast the result to what that version of MISRA called *underlying type* - the type an expression would have had if not for implicit promotion. So you'd write `(uint8_t)~0U`. This rule of underlying type was a bit blunt and misguided however, the current concept of essential type works better and is easier to understand. If you have an old tool checking for MISRA C:2004 compliance then the warning makes perfect sense.

Either way, the recommended practice is to always cast the result of `~` to the unsigned type intended to be used by the expression. That way you can't go wrong.